# Kendo DropDownListFor возвращает выбранный текст а не значение

Tags: kendo

```
@Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Status).ValuePrimitive(true).DataTextField("Aspirants1").DataValueField("New_kod").BindTo(ViewBag.Type).Value(((IEnumerable<Aspirants>)ViewBag.Type).First().New_Kod.ToString())

$("#Status").data("kendoDropDownList").value()
```

или
    $('#Status').val()
возвращает DataTextField а не DataValueField

хотя на этой же странице есть элемент
    @Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x => x.Kod_tipap).ValuePrimitive(true).DataTextField("Tipp1").DataValueField("Kod_tipp").BindTo(ViewBag.Tipp).Value(((IEnumerable)ViewBag.Tipp).First().Kod_tipp.ToString())

и здесь всё работает

```
        ViewBag.Tipp = _db.Tipp.ToList();
        ViewBag.Type = _db.AspiratsTypes.ToList();

public virtual DbSet<Aspirants> AspiratsTypes { get; set; }

public partial class Aspirants
{
    [Key]
    public int New_Kod { get; set; }

    [Column("Aspirants")]
    public string Aspirants1 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

New_Kod регистр буквы не совпадал. В классе свойство отличалось от того что прописано в определении DDL DataValueField.